# Bartle - 4.1 - Limits of Functions - Example (e)

Tags: analysis

From Introduction to Real Analysis, 4th Edition. Page 107, example (e).

Can someone explain the algebraic operations that were performed to get |x-2| factored out in the manner illustrated in the example? It's not making sense to me. For example, if I go in reverse and distribute |x-2| back in, I end up with a 5x^4 term.

I've included an excerpt of the example with includes the manipulation I'm unsure of. Thank you.

[image: Excerpt from example.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, $5x^3+6x+12$ should be $5x^2+6x+12$.

Note that

$$5x^3-4x^2-24=(5x^2+6x+12)(x-2)$$

Comment: Yes, thank you, the distribution results in the original expression now. I was thinking it might have been a typo; but I wasn't confident enough to rule out I was making some kind of simple mistake. I really appreciate the nearly instant response. Thank you again.

Comment: @Justin if you are satisfied with an answer, you should accept it by clicking on the green arrow check. That way you say thanks to someone who is helping you out.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, I've done that.